# How to I insert code snippets in the VBA editor?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put together a collection of code snippets that I use most often, and I would want to have a way of inserting them where in the VBA editor.

Right now i'm using the code below to copy the snippet to clipboard, but I still need to paste it myself.
Is there a more direct way that would insert the snippet in the VBA editor, where I select, without me having to paste?

The `pasteClipboard` subroutine below does not work in the VBA editor :(

```
Private Sub copyCodeToClipboard(codeType As enCodeSnippets)
    Dim codeText
    codeText = getCodeText(codeType)
    copyToClipboard codeText
End Sub

Sub copyToClipboard(textI)
    'GLOBAL CALLER TO COPY TEXT TO CLIPBOARD
    Dim DObj As New DataObject
    
    DObj.SetText (textI)
    DObj.PutInClipboard
End Sub

Sub pasteClipboard()
    Application.SendKeys "^v", True
End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than copying the code snippet, could you not just create a module that you import to your projects when you open workbook? This way you will always have the latest version in all your projects

Comment: You can use a code library or something like https://www.mztools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by sending keys 1 by one, after a delay. My previous code with the clipboard started failing, because on paste it would return "??" instead of the actual text.

```
Sub sendKeysOneByOne(codeType As enCodeSnippets)
    'USE THIS MACRO TO CREATE CODE IN VBA
    Dim textI, I, letterToSend, waitSeconds
    
    textI = getCodeText(codeType)
    waitSeconds = 3
    
    For I = 1 To waitSeconds
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        Application.StatusBar = "Pasting  where your mouse is in " & waitSeconds - I & " seconds"
        DoEvents
    Next
    
    For I = 1 To Len(textI)
        letterToSend = Mid(textI, I, 1)
        SendKeys letterToSend
    Next
    
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Shell object to send the key strokes to paste the content of the clipboard like this:

```
Sub pasteClipboard()
    Dim keys As String
    Dim wsh As Object
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    keys = "^v"
    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wsh.SendKeys keys, True
    Set wsh = Nothing
End Sub
```

The wait time is optional. I personally ran the code without it and it worked.
This was inspired by Jan Karel Pieterse's answer to [this thread](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-38826.html).